# Removing Polyphony from Audio

Tags: artificial-intelligence, audio-processing

here's an interesting question:

Suppose I have an audio recording of a C major chord (C-E-G) played on the piano, which I would like to separate into three separate audio files - one with only C, one with only E, and one with only G playing (even a single audio file of a single note would suffice). I know software like Melodyne is capable of doing such things but would love for anyone to guide me in the right direction here.

What I've already tried: writing a neural network to do this (but honestly that feels like overkill.. this shouldn't be *that* challenging), and playing with the STFT and trying to figure something out from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The STFT approach could work. Start with the spectrums for each note individually. Then look at pairs to see how the notes interact. There's also a technique known as a [wavelet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet) which may be useful.